# Two scripts adding different listeners to the same element

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, dom-events

I am using D3 selection statement to access HTML date input from 2 different scripts.

But, only the last script is able to access the date , not the previous ones. The code below depicts my problem .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>

</head>
<body>


  From <input id="dateFrom" type="date" > To <input id="dateTo" type="date"><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send Request">


<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">


var data=[{"time":new Date('Tue Jan 30 2018 01:58:57 GMT+0100 (CET)'),"value":1},{"time":new Date('Wed Jan 31 2018 01:58:57 GMT+0100 (CET)'),"value":1}
  ,{"time":new Date('Thu Feb 01 2018 01:58:57 GMT+0100 (CET)'),"value":1},{"time":new Date('Fri Feb 02 2018 01:58:57 GMT+0100 (CET)'),"value":1},{"time":new Date('Sat Feb 03 2018 01:58:57 GMT+0100 (CET)'),"value":1}
,{"time":new Date('Sun Feb 04 2018 01:58:57 GMT+0100 (CET)'),"value":1},{"time":new Date(' Mon Feb 05 2018 01:58:57 GMT+0100 (CET)'),"value":1}];

var dateF;
var dateT;

d3.select('#dateFrom')
  .on('input',function()
      {
        dateF = new Date(d3.select('#dateFrom').property('value'))
      });

d3.select('#dateTo')
  .on('input',function()
      {
        dateT = new Date(d3.select('#dateTo').property('value'))
      });

  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">


var dataFiltered1;
  d3.select('#submit')
    .on('click',function(){
      dataFiltered1=data.filter(function(d){
        return d.time>=dateF && d.time<=dateT;
      });
      console.log(dataFiltered1);
    });

  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  var dataFiltered2;
  d3.select('#submit')
    .on('click',function(){
      dataFiltered2=data.filter(function(d){
        return d.time>=dateF && d.time<=dateT;
      });
      console.log(dataFiltered2);
    });
  </script>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You will observe that only `dataFiltered2` in the last script will be logged to the console and `dataFiltered1` will not receive the date input and hence will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

That's the expected behaviour. The second script adds a new event listener, which overrides the first one.

The [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_on) is clear about this:

> selection.on(typenames[, listener[, capture]])
>
> Adds or removes a listener to each selected element for the specified event typenames [...] The optional name allows **multiple callbacks** to be registered to receive events of the same type, such as `click.foo` and `click.bar`. (emphasis mine)

Have a look at this demo, where two scripts add listeners to the same elements:

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="date">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send Request">
<script>
  //this is script 1
  var foo;
  d3.select("#date").on("input.foo", function() {
    foo = this.value
  })
  d3.select('#submit').on('click.foo', function() {
    console.log("foo: " + foo);
  });
</script>
<script>
  //this is script 2
  var baz;
  d3.select("#date").on("input.baz", function() {
    baz = this.value
  })
  d3.select('#submit').on('click.baz', function() {
    console.log("baz: " + baz);
  });
</script>
```

Pay attention to the fact that each event has different names for the types.